# Virtual method in C++ fails to get mocked. What am I missing here?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, mocking

I have following setup:

```
Class DataFetcher {
  public:
    virtual ~DataFetcher() = default;
    explicit DataFetcher(const Backends& backends);

    virtual vector<Data> GetData(const vector<string>& q) const;

  private:
    Backends backends_;
};
```

Implementation:

```
vector<Data> DataFetcher::GetData(const vector<string>& q) {
  cout << "Yikes! This was called";
  ...
}
```

Then a piece of function in another place which uses it as:

```
void Process(const Backends& backends) {
  DataFetcher data_fetcher(backends);
  ...
  const auto& data = data_fetcher.GetData(q);
  ...
}
```

Now I am trying to test `Process` with any call to `GetData` being mocked, as following:

```
class MockDataFetcher : public DataFetcher {
  public:
    using DataFetcher::DataFetcher;
    MOCK_METHOD(vector<Data>, GetData, (const vector<string>& q), (const, override));
}

class ActualLogicTest : public ... {
  protected:
    Backends backends_;
}

TEST_F(ActualLogicTest, BasicOne) {
  MockDataFetcher mock_data_fetcher(backends_);
  vector<Data> data;
  ON_CALL(mock_data_fetcher, GetData).WillByDefault(Return(data));
  ...
  Process(backends_);
}
```

What is wrong in this? I am seeing that actual implementation of `GetData` is getting called and I am seeing that message `Yikes! This was called` too. Since GetData is a virtual function, it should get the empty vector of Data back as result from the mocked one. Why is that not happening?

Finally the test crashes because backend doesn't have initialization of its members.

Comment: Can you explain what value `GetData` has returned?

Comment: please show a [mre] but it doesn't look like `Process` is using your mock object?

Comment: Ivan, edited my question to add more details. Test crashes inside GetData because of backends not initialized.

Comment: Alan, Process initializes DataFetcher inside it. And yes it is not using my mock object. It should.. Right?

Comment: You need to change `DataFetcher data_fetcher(backends);` to `MockDataFetcher data_fetcher(backends);`.  The code, as currently implemented, has hard-coded `DataFetcher`, but in order to be unit testable it needs to not be hard-coded and instead passed in.

Comment: [tag:gmock] is for Groovy language, your code is C++. Do you need a Groovy answer? `Class` is not a C++ keyword, you don't even seem to use C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function doesn't use `mock` object at all:

```cpp
void Process(const Backends& backends) {
  DataFetcher data_fetcher(backends);
  ...
  const auto& data = data_fetcher.GetData(q);
  ...
}
```

Regardless whether you create a `MockDataFetcher` the `Process` function create local `DataFetcher` and uses it - not the `mock` that you have created in test case - you need to provide it somehow to the `Process` function.

Answer (score -2):

From your declaration:

```
virtual vector<Data> GetData(const vector<string>& q) const;
```

GetData() returns an object.

Yet, in Process(),

```
void Process(const Backends& backends) {
  DataFetcher data_fetcher(backends);
  ...
  const auto& data = data_fetcher.GetData(q);  // BUG!! Why is data a reference?

}
```

The variable 'data' cannot be a reference, since the object it refers to has literally no life span. Any attempt  to use 'data' will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: taking a const reference to a temporary isn't necessarily a bug (though it probably isn't the intended behaviour here)

Comment: This is incorrect due to *lifetime extension* that is applicable here.